# When is there a subring of the complex numbers surjecting onto a given field of prime characteristic?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-representation-theory

To make use of the Lie algebra action of $\mathsf{gl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ to establish a isomorphism in modular representation theory, I would like an answer to this question:

> Let $K$ be a field of prime characteristic. When is there a subring $R$ of the complex numbers and a maximal ideal $M$ of $R$ such that $R/M \cong K$?

Clearly no such ring $R$ exists if $K$ has strictly more than $|\mathbb{C}|$ independent transcendental elements. Is this the only obstruction? Is there a reasonably explicit way to construct a suitable $R$ when $K$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$?

As a follow-up (which at first I thought I needed, but I now see I can get around by working with $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ rather than $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$), note that if $R/M \cong K$ then the induced map $\mathrm{GL}_d(R) \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}_d(K)$, defined on a $d \times d$ matrix with entries in $R$ by applying $R \twoheadrightarrow R/M \cong K$ to each entry, is a surjective group homomorphism.

> Is is true in general that the restriction of the group homomorphism $\mathrm{GL}_d(R) \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}_d(K)$ to $\mathrm{SL}_d(R)$ is surjective onto $\mathrm{SL}_d(K)$, or are there further obstructions?

Comment: If $X$ is a transcendence base for $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb Q$, then the subring it generates is a free commutative ring over $X$. That subring has a surjection onto any ring of cardinality at most $|X|=|\mathbb C|$.

Comment: Follow-up question: yes (exercise). Hint: elementary matrices.

Comment: Clearly this is very easy for some people. But it genuinely comes up in my research and I think the down-voters are being rather harsh.

Comment: @MarkWildon Not shure that downvotes come from easy-solvers (the question of constructibility remains open though) (+1)

Comment: @YCor: is the point of your hint that the elementary matrices with entries in $R$ generate $\mathrm{SL}_d(R)$? But this is false when $d=2$ and $R = \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$, as I think was first shown by Cohn, and is mentioned in the introduction to Suslin's paper, On the structure of the special linear group over polynomial rings.

Comment: @MarkWildon no, it's that it generates $SL_d(K)$ for $K$ a field, and the arrow is in the right direction. The map $SL_d(R)\to SL_d(K)$ is already surjective in restriction to the elementary subgroup $E_d(R)$.

Comment: @YCor: Thank you, I now see it is not very hard.

Comment: An algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is given by $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p = R/M$ where $R$ is the ring of algebraic integers and $M$ any maximal ideal containing $p$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The complex numbers have transcendence degree the continuum over $\mathbb Q$ so contain a copy of the field of rational functions in continuum many variables over $\mathbb Q$. This in turn contains the ring of polynomials in continuum many variables over $\mathbb Z$, which surjects onto any ring of cardinality at most the continuum.

Comment: Thank you. This answers my first question. Maybe it's too much to ask for a more explicit construction, but I would be interested to know when the subring can be taken inside the ring of algebraic integers of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @MarkWildon I think the construction of a transcendence basis of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (or one of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$) is not easy (up to my untutored knowledge, only 3 explicit algebraically independent elements are known !).

Comment: The subring can be taken inside the algebraic integers iff $K$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$. For, let $R$ be the ring of algebraic integers in $\mathbb{C}$. Since any subring $S$ of $R$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Z}$, the quotient of $S$ by a maximal ideal $m$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ where $(p)=\mathbb{Z}\cap m$. ...

Comment: ... Conversely, let $K$ be an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$. Let $M$ be a maimal ideal of $R$ containing $p$. Then $R/M$ is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$. Hence we can assume $K \le R/M$. Let $\pi: R \to R/M$ and let $S = \pi^{-1}(K)$. Then $L=S/(M \cap S)$. qed